# ZAP cli reporting different results

Tags: owasp, zap

Why `[INFO]` shows Issues found: 0 while the report states otherwise?
Just to be sure I did restart zap proxy as well as changed API key and run everything inside docker.

[image]

And here is the output from the console:

```
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123 shutdown
[INFO]            Shutting down ZAP daemon
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123 status
[ERROR]           ZAP is not running
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli  start -o '-config api.key=123'
[INFO]            Starting ZAP daemon
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123 status
[INFO]            ZAP is running
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123 report -o /working/output/report.md -f md; cat output/report.md
[INFO]            Report saved to "/working/output/report.md"

# ZAP Scanning Report




## Summary of Alerts

| Risk Level | Number of Alerts |
| --- | --- |
| High | 0 |
| Medium | 0 |
| Low | 0 |
| Informational | 0 |

## Alert Detail

gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123  quick-scan -o '-config scanner.attackOnStart=true -config view.mode=attack -config connection.dnsTtlSuccessfulQueries=-1 -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true' -s xss,sqli --spider --recursive http://127.0.0.1:9009
[INFO]            Running a quick scan for http://127.0.0.1:9009
[INFO]            Issues found: 0
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123 report -o /working/output/report.md -f md; head output/report.md                                                                                                                                                    [INFO]            Report saved to "/working/output/report.md"

# ZAP Scanning Report
## Summary of Alerts

| Risk Level | Number of Alerts |
| --- | --- |
gauntlt@724fe0361390:/working$ zap-cli --api-key=123 report -o /working/output/report.md -f md; head -20 output/report.md
[INFO]            Report saved to "/working/output/report.md"

# ZAP Scanning Report

## Summary of Alerts
| Risk Level | Number of Alerts |
| --- | --- |
| High | 0 |
| Medium | 1 |
| Low | 3 |
| Informational | 0 |
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

did you resolved your issue? 
I had the same issue,
I did a cat on the zap.log and I found that my ip address was not allowed, I added it to the allowed ip address on the setting > API > allow IPs and than it works for me, otherwise you need to check you firewall connection with telnet ...